# Help flags with Console App

Tags: c#, command-line, console

I'm using Visual Studio C# Express 2010 to make a console application. I've implemented the 'commands' as if sections in the Prompt method calling a command method, eg

```
if (line == "help")
            {
                Help();
            }
```

That gives you a help page on my program. If it needs cleaning up that's fine.

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can, say, have the user type in a command followed by ? and get command-specific help, rather than just a blanket help page. I don't have any code attempts because I deleted them earlier, but I'll keep coding.

Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an article detailing a fairly fully functional [Command Line Parser in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/command_line.aspx).

It demonstrates how to parse complex command lines following the "standard" techniques of specifying information on a command line.

Comment: nice, but note that solution there doesn't follow one of the conventions where by single dash is used for "short options" that can be combined. e.g. -lr does NOT translate to -l -r using the code in the link. There is no differentiation there b/w single and double dash options.

Answer (score 0):

```
 `if (line.indexof("?") != -1) Help()`
```